# JRebel for Android with Maven and IntelliJ

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, jrebel

I'm interested in utilizing [JRebel for Android](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel-for-android/), but an established project on which I'm working utilizes Maven.  Furthermore, all the developers are using IntelliJ, as opposed to Android Studio.

It seems as if JRebel has plugins for [Maven](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/maven.html#maven-rebel-xml) and IntelliJ; however, I was wondering if anyone was able to add Android to this mix.

Not surprisingly, JRebel for Android integrates easily with Gradle and Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the PM for JRebel for Android.

JRebel for Android supports only Gradle based Android Studio projects at the moment. We are working on adding IntelliJ support. However at the moment we have no plans to start supporting Maven. Sadly JRebel Maven plugin won't help here either as these are two different products.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Sten.